# Is it possible to query Google Drive via SDK using a regular expression?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a very large file hierarchy in Google Drive which follows a standard naming convention.

Is it possible to issue a list query that returns Folder Name and ID for all folders matching a specific pattern?

I can't seem to find this in the documentation, so I'm thinking that it may not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible as you already found out since its not on the docs.